# An intuitive way of saving a D3JS chart to image using Java?

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, d3.js, png

Is there a way to save a D3JS generated Chart Image to file (PNG ideally) using Java language at all?

If its not possible at all, happy to hear alternative NodeJS kind of options as well.

My primary server code is in Java/SpringBoot, hence this question this rather awkward way.
Apologies in advance.

Feel free to suggest refinements to the question itself.

Comment: Have you looked for a Java library, which saves svg or base64 as a png? If you have that, then it shouldn't be too hard to send the data from the front end to your Java back end and save it.

Comment: [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/) can read SVG and produce a `BufferedImage`, that in turn can be stored as PNG or any other format. It uses [Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) to read SVG, you might be able to use it directly too.

Comment: @Geshode, I want to do all in the backend though. No frontend available. If necessary can pull off a NodeJS server at max.

Comment: So, how would you create the d3 chart, if you don't use any front end and have a Java server?

Comment: That's the idea. Just to start as a wild one. Assuming we could find a way to the end-goal. :-)

Comment: I am not a front-end master, so apologies for my silly interpretations. Since Node.JS possibility is there, I was thinking if the same JS code in the browser could be perhaps running in the server to do the needs, thus possibly generating the charts on the server end.